# how to obtain value from scanner without printing on screen

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm creating a sorting machine using a USB scanner and raspberry pi. The bar code value scanned must be checked in the database. If its marked as pass then machine continues to move, else if its marked as fail in database then the machine stops. Now I dont want the scanner input to be printed on the screen, how can I use the bar code value in the program without printing on screen. Im using python to program.

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import Tkinter as tk
    import MySQLdb



   #creating window and entry box
   root=Tk()
   root.title("PCBA Registration")



    entry=Entry(root,fg="black",bg="white",width=15)
    entry.grid(row=0,column=4,sticky=W)
    entry_value=entry.get()
   #label
    label1=Label(root,bg="black",fg="white",text="SCAN   HERE").grid(row=0,column=2,stick=W)

    def check():
          db=MySQLdb.connect (host='localhost', user = "root", passwd = "passwd", db = "server")

   #creation of cursor to access database
      cur=db.cursor()
      do1="SELECT Workorder_No FROM pcba_registration where PCB_Sno='%s'" %(entry.get())
      cur.execute(do1)
workorder=cur.fetchall()
      for row1 in workorder:
            print row1[0]
            workorder_value=row1[0]
      do2=("SELECT approval_Status FROM workorder_release where  workOrder_No='%s'" %(workorder_value))
      cur.execute(do2)
      status=cur.fetchall()
      print status
      for row2 in status:
          print row2[0]    

  check=Button(root,text="CHECK",width=5,command=check).grid(row=2,column=4,stick=W)

     #to run main loop
    if __name__ == '__main__':
          root.mainloop()
```

For now I have created an interface using Tkinter to to print out the scanned bar code. But I dont want that. Im an absolute beginner and new to stack overlflow too. Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: i don't see any scan part of your code.

Comment: I dont know how to obtain value from USB scanner. Thats why for now im typing out the PCB serial number. @ADWAN

Comment: and where is scan part in your code can you post that one so i can work around that.